# Haskell Paperfolding

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function, `fold n`, where `n` is the number of times a piece of paper is folded in the same direction. The function should output a string of `"m"`'s (mountain) and `"v"`'s (valley) representing the folds in the paper. For example, `fold 1` would output `"v"`, `fold 2` would output `"mvv"`, and so on. I'm pretty new to Haskell and was looking for any suggestions as to how to approach this.

Comment: First thing you need to do is figure out how each new fold changes what was there before. Can you see any patterns? Can you write down an informal description of those patterns?

Comment: I suggest working through this by hand...with an actual piece of paper. This will help you to find the patterns. For example, how does `fold 2` result in `"mvv"`?

Comment: This is known as dragon curve. [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve) has a quite complte treatment including the algorithm. It's also in oeis as https://oeis.org/A014577 including codes in various languages that can easily be translated.

Answer (score 1):

Given an existing sequence of folds, adding a fold needs to intersperse an alternating sequence of characters `'m'` and `'v'`, starting before the first, and ending after the last.

As it happens, Haskell has a function called `intersperse`, but it inserts the *same* element between values, not including the beginning or end; you will have to roll your own.

In the functional style, you can do this with mutually recursive functions:

```
add_fold_m (first : rest) = 'm' : first : add_fold_v rest
add_fold_m [] = "m"
-- note that "m" is a string of one char, while 'm' is that char itself

add_fold_v (first : rest) = 'v' : first : add_fold_m rest
add_fold_v [] = "v"
```

Then, you can start with a `"v"`, and apply `add_fold_m` as many times as you have folds.  You can use the Haskell prelude function `iterate` here:

```
fold n = iterate add_fold_m "v" !! n
```

The function `iterate` actually generates a list, of the results of applying a function (its first argument) multiple times to a value (its second argument):

```
iterate f x
--> [x, f x, f (f x), f (f (f x)), ...]
```

Note that the result is an infinite list.  Haskell is lazy by default, so this is fine unless you try to demand the whole list -- `iterate` will only generate list items on demand.

The `!!` operator is the list-indexing operator:  `(list !! n)` returns the `n`th element of `list`.